# clustMixType version 0.2-11 cannot find silhouette_kproto

Tags: r

I'm trying to run the example of the silhouette_kproto function from the documentation:

https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/clustMixType/versions/0.2-2/topics/silhouette_kproto

I've installed v 0.2-11 as shown in my SessionInfo()

```
other attached packages:
[1] clustMixType_0.2-11 readxl_1.1.0
```

But it seems that this version does not include the silhouette_kproto function, this function seems to be in version 0.2-2 as shown here:

https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/clustMixType/versions/0.2-2/topics/silhouette_kproto

How could I install the 0.2-2 version of clustMixType? I've just run this

```
install.packages('clustMixType')
```

Is it supposed to insall the last version?

I've searched for it using

```
> getAnywhere(silhouette_kproto)
```

And it was found:

```
A single object matching ‘silhouette_kproto’ was found
It was found in the following places
  namespace:clustMixType
```

Why then I get the error message when I try tu use it?

```
could not find function "silhouette_kproto"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The example you are referring to is from the documentation from an older version.

Please try to reproduce the example from the new version, we have restructured the functions and you should now use `validation_kproto(method = "silhouette", ...)` ([have a look here](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/clustMixType/clustMixType.pdf)).

Many greetings Rabea

[clustmixtype](/questions/tagged/clustmixtype)